# RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number in cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-composer

i run pyspark job in cloud composser gcp, it was running perfectly before but the after a few minutes the

RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

some people say that it has to be a problem with JAVA_HOME path, since i run it in cloud composser i have no idea how to tackle this error.

i really appreciate for your help!

i've searsching all day long but still cannot figure it our the solution